# Find (Based on string name), Select, Copy & Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to figure out how to construct a vba code that searches across cells "A10000:XFD10000" for a string named "Apple" and copies that range until cells "A1:A10000" and pastes it into another tab within the same sheet called "Validation" in row "A".

Macro below

```
Sub Get_Date()

    Dim Partname As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set sh = Sheets("Tests")
    Set ws = Sheets("Part Catalog")
    Partname = ActiveCell.Value

    ws.Cells.Find(Partname).Offset(0, 1).Copy
    sh.Cells.Find(Partname).Offset(0, 1).Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry but your question is kind of unclear. What do you mean with *copies that range until cells "A1:A10000* ? paste `Apple` in range A1:A10000? Can you add a data example with expected output?

Comment: After finding the data the macro should select that range and copy data until cells "1:10000" and add sheet rename it to "Validations" and paste it there. I am unable to paste my code it shows formatting error. However, you can reach out me on - luv3lectro@gmail.com for the codes. Thanks for your interest in this :)